# How to set Laravel Model table/collection dynamically?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, model

I am using GitHub - jenssegers/laravel-mongodb: A MongoDB based Eloquent model and Query builder for Laravel;
In my Laravel project I created DB model that sets Model table name dynamically (in Mongodb case collection) .

```
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class DbData extends Model
    {   
        protected   $collection = 'default_collection';
        function __construct($collection)
            {
                $this->collection = $collection;
            }
    }
```

This works when I am creating new DbData object, for data insert:

```
$data = new DbData('dynamic_collection_name');
$data->variable = 'Test';
$data->save();
```

But this solution is not enough of I want to use this DbData model for querying data from my database.
    What I want to achieve is to add possibility to pass variable for DbModel, for instance something like this:

```
$data = DbData::setCollection('dynamic_collection_name');
$data->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could perhaps do something like this on your class.

```
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class DbData extends Model
{   
    protected   $collection = 'default_collection';

    public function __construct($collection)
    {
        $this->collection = $collection;
    }

    public static function setCollection($collection)
    {
        return new self($collection);
    }
}
```

This will allow you to call `DbData::setCollection('collection_name')` and the collection name will only be set for that specific instance.

Comment: This returns error: Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance

Comment: It sounds like somewhere you are doing `$data->id`. In which case, this won't work because you are getting a laravel collection back. Instead you need to do `$data->first()->id` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class DbData extends Eloquent
{
    use HasFactory;

    // if you need to set default collection also then uncomment below line.
    // protected $collection = 'defaultCollectionIfWantsToSet';

    /**
     * set collection name
     *
     * @param  string $collection
     * @return $this
     */
    public static function setCollection($collection)
    {
        $instance = new self();
        $instance->collection = $collection;
        return $instance;
    }

    // OR you can use function as like below also
    // public static function setCollection($collection)
    // {
    //     $instance = new self();
    //     return $instance->setTable($collection);
    // }
}
```

this will allow you to call DbData::setCollection('collection_name') and the collection name will only be set for that specific instance

I tested with Laravel 8 & 9